# Solving multitab data conflict in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, request

We're developing a Spring MVC application and we have a Controller which is defined like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("item")
public class ItemController {
```

if the user opens two tabs to edit two different items at a time, when he saves the first, it overwrites the second...

I get this happens because of the `@SessionAttributes("item")` annotation but how do we achieve the multi-tab approach?

We thought of getting rid of the `@SessionAttributes` annotation and load the item to be edited as a model attribute, but then we have to load all the data that is not edited as hidden fields so that they don't get lost when the user hits save...

Is there any less rudimentary option?

Comment: There is only one session per browser, so use a request attribute instead

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773320/spring-mvc-prg-pattern-with-multiple-tabs-session-workaround?rq=1